# Calling Matchbox keyboard from a web application

Tags: keyboard, kiosk

I'm creating a kiosk style display running a locally hosted web information application.
All command/selections etc are by web buttons etc so I don't need a keyboard during normal operation.
However to close it down I need to break-into the secure kiosk by pressing ctrl+alt+bkspace
Can I either send this sequence fro a web page button or have a button to call a virtual keyboard so I can enter the key sequence. I have matchbox keyboard installed with a desktop shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

Due to security, Chromium does not allow websites to start up programs. Imagine the consequences if it did!

There is a way to do it though: Get a Chrome extension.
[This](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/virtual-keyboard/pflmllfnnabikmfkkaddkoolinlfninn?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) is one such on-screen-keyboard. It's advertised to pop up automatically when the user clicks inside a text box.
[image]